# Add tab to TabControl from template

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I'm making a simple chat app. I would like to have different conversations in tabs. When user opens a new conversation, I would like to add new tab for him. The conversation tabs will probably look very similar, only the content will differ. Is there any elegant way to accomplish this? I would like to setup a template for the conversation window, and then reuse it.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx  You can make a Template for your TabItem.

Comment: @JLott hmm, any examples? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: This looks like a really good example, you can even download the source code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33598/A-nice-approach-for-a-LOB-WPF-application

Comment: I would highly recommend using MVVM. You would bind your `TabControl` to a collection of `ChatViewModels`, and when you want to open a new "tab", you would add a new `ChatViewModel` to the collection and set the `SelectedIndex` to the new item. To modify how the tab looks, just change the template in the TabItem style

Answer (score 0):

well you can check out my messenger control. I think it's pretty simple
https://vstalk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#release_2_1/VSTalk/VSTalk.Engine/View/CommonChatFrame.xaml